# how to compile or run a python program in fedora?

Tags: python, fedora

How do I run a simple python program in fedora?

I am very much new to fedora and i don't know how exactly to start in fedora. Do we need to install any software in fedora to make python programs work? Please tell me step by step how to do it. I am familiar with IDLE but not in fedora.

Answer (score 7):

Put

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the top of your file. Then on the command line do

```
$ chmod u+x your_python_file.py
```

(I use `$` to indicate a shell prompt, don't type that.) 
You can run the file with

```
$ ./yourpythonfile.py
```

You can also just do

```
$ python yourpythonfile.py
```

and don't need the `#!/usr....` or `$ chmod ...` stuff, but the first approach is the natural way to do things in unix.

Comment: +1. And if Python isn't installed, run `yum install python` from a shell (command-line) with root privileges.

Comment: or `sudo yum install` and then enter your super user password. I am pretty sure python ships with all the major linux distros though.

Comment: @Cameron This doesn't make much sense as yum depends on python :)

Comment: how can i know which python libraries are there in my fedora's python?and how to add more library if i want to add.can i know which version of python is installed in fedora?help me out plz

Answer (score 1):

In Fedora python is already installed. Just run in the command line:

```
 python ./yourProgram.py
```

Comment: how can i know which python libraries are there in my fedora's python?and how to add more library if i want to add.can i know which version of python is installed in fedora?help me out plz

Comment: python --version will give you the python version. I do not use Fedora so I do not know the exact path to the python libraries, but the path is stated in the man page of python.